# Translating a string to "robber's language"

Tags: python, string, function

I'm trying to practice for my upcoming practical programming test so have been browsing online for examples and came across this

"Write a function translate() that will translate a text into "rövarspråket" (Swedish for "robber's language"). That is, double every consonant and place an occurrence of "o" in between. For example, translate("this is fun") should return the string "tothohisos isos fofunon".

I don't know why but I'm struggling with this a lot. So simple but yet I'm having a difficult time. Here is what I have tried

```
def translate(n):
    consonant="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"
    for letters in n:
        if letters in consonant:
            return (letters+"O"+letters)
        else:
            return("Vowel")
```

I'm sorry if my coding is super amateur. Just trying to learn :/

Comment: You're using `return` to exit the function when you should be appending the letters onto a new string.

Comment: Do you want the case of "O" to be the same as the consonant?

Comment: `''.join([x+'O'+x if x in consonants else x for x in n])`

Answer (score 4):

```
consonants = set("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ")
original_string = "this is fun"
translated = ''.join(map(lambda x: x+"0"+x if x in consonants else x,original_string)
print translated
```

is one way I might do this ... this just maps each letter to letter+0+letter if its a consonant and then joins the resulting lists

Answer (score 1):

```
    mytext = 'thisisfun'
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstuvwxyz'
newtext = []
def translate(mytext):
    for i in mytext:
        if i not in consonants:
            newtext.append(i)
        else:
            newtext.append(i)
            newtext.append('o')
            newtext.append(i)
    print(newtext)

translate(mytext)
```

It presents the result as a list right now, just working on a way to get it back to a string for you... ask if you have any queries, its working OK for me right now... there are more elegant ways to do, I'm working on it right now - you've given me something to do for 10 minutes at least!

Answer (score 1):

`return` is the end of a function.  Full stop.  You can only return one thing.  So you need to *accumulate* some values within your loop, then `return` it at the end.  I'll leave that to you if you want to tweak your existing code.

Your way of thinking - initially return a thing, maintain state, and continue on from there next go-around, is actually how a **generator** works:

```
def translate(n):
    consonants = set("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ")
    for letter in n:
        if letter in consonants:
            yield '{}o{}'.format(letter,letter)
        else:
            yield letter

''.join(translate('this is fun'))
Out[44]: 'tothohisos isos fofunon'
```

Brushed up a few things, but the heart of your code is there.

So... yeah.  Having written this, I'm not sure what you're looking for in an answer.  If you're looking for alternate ways to write it, here is what I'd probably do:

```
from string import ascii_letters
def translate(s):
    consonants = set(ascii_letters) - set('aeiouAEIOU')
    def _mapper(c):
        return '{}o{}'.format(c,c) if c in consonants else c
    return ''.join(map(_mapper, s))
```

Comment: Don't you mean consonants instead of vowels?

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right lines but the `return` means that you would only ever get one character back from the function.

Here's a slightly modified version of your function that builds a new string and `return`s it at the end:

```
def translate(n):
    consonants = set("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ")
    ret_str = ""
    for letter in n:
        if letter in consonants:
            ret_str += letter + ("o" if letter.islower() else "O") + letter
        else:
            ret_str += letter
    return ret_str
```

I'm using [`str.islower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) to determine whether the "o" should be uppercase or not.

In general, testing for membership in a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) is faster than testing for membership in strings, lists or other types of collections so I've included that above. This could be seen as premature optimisation however, as making a set object will probably cost you about as much time as testing for membership in a set will save...

If you're not concerned about the case of the "o", you could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead, like this:

```
''.join([ s + "o" + s if s in consonant else s for s in n ])
```

The part in the `[ ]` is a list comprehension, which returns a list. [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is then used to combine the elements of the list into a single string.

This would be a bit messy if you also wanted to check for upper or lower case:

```
''.join([ s+"o"+s if s.islower() else s+"O"+s if s in consonant else s for s in n ])
```

Answer (score 1):

my knowledge about python is very short , but i think the Author have forget to write a empty string , and this add to letters, after for loop ...

```
def traslate():
  a = raw_input("Please give a sentence: ")
  b = ""
  for i in a:
     b += i
     if i in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz":
           b += "o" + i
  print "You answer translate into 'robber' language: " + b

traslate(n)
```

Maybe you like this....

```
def translate(n):
    b = ""
    consonant = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
    for letters in n: 
          b += letters           # you add first time the consonant
          if letters in consonant:
                b += "0" + letters  #you add 0 and seconds consonant
          else:
              return ("Vowel")

print translate ("this is funk")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstuvwxyz'
def translate(mytext):
    newtext = ""
    for i in mytext:
        if i in consonants:
            newtext+=i+'o'+i                
        else:
            newtext+=i
    return newtext
#Enter any text by using mytext variable
mytext = input("Enter Text")
translatedText=translate(mytext)
print("After translation the text is:",translatedText)
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.